# Passing Bool Value from one viewcontroller to another in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, boolean

I am trying to send a BOOL value from 
`ViewController A` to `ViewController B`.
On `ViewController A`, `dashboard.skip` shows `YES`, but on 
`ViewController B`, `self.skip` shows `NO`.

```
- (IBAction)skipToDashboard:(UIButton *)sender {
    ViewController B *vc=[[ViewController B alloc]init];
    vc.presentButtonTag=sender.tag;
    self.fromSkip=YES;
    vc.skip=self.fromSkip;
}
```

In `ViewController B`:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL skip;
```

Comment: you can create a BOOL Property to ViewController B and Pass the Value from ViewController A and ByDefault BOOL Property value is FALSE so handle your code accordingly.  if there is still issue so please let me know.

Comment: I have already made a property in ViewController B i.i.@property (nonatomic) BOOL skip; but its not working

Comment: you have to create one bool variable in appdelegate and use it your viewcontroller

Comment: What did you do with `vc` in your code example? Did you present this controller?

Comment: @birendra...Thanks,it worked!

Comment: @TestShroff show how you are getting `fromSkip` value this will definitely results 1 to next vc.

Comment: How you are pushing your view to next by Storyboard segue or by coding ?

Comment: Suggestion : Its a wrong way to keep BOOL value in AppDelegate as we need that in single VC so we can take it in same VC not globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to pass your data from First screen to 2nd screen.

**1st Way:**

You can pass your data by creating VC object and assign value in it and push to next screen like below example.

**Code :**

```
//Initilize view controller from storyboard id.
ViewController *objViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

//Assign value
objViewController.presentButtonTag=sender.tag;
self.fromSkip=YES;
objViewController.skip=self.fromSkip;

//Push view
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objViewController animated:YES];
```

**2nd Way:**

By Storyboard you can set segue action on button and in prepare segue method you need to pass your data like this.

**Code:**

```
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ViewController"]) {
        ViewController *objViewController = (ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        objViewController.selectedTag = ((UIButton*) sender).tag;
       //Assign value
      objViewController.presentButtonTag=sender.tag;
      self.fromSkip=YES;
      objViewController.skip=self.fromSkip;
    }
}
```

Now you can check your scenario in both condition I think you are pushing to next screen by storyboard so use `2nd Way`.

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define BOOL property and set value either true or false.

For Ex: Appdelegate declare property and then use

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL fromSkip;
```

Comment: This is not working ...it still gives NO on ViewController B.Please help

Comment: @TestShroff Then you need to synthesize property

Comment: Done that also,but no results...

Comment: @TestShroff please follow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?rq=1)